# Keep the value of a string secret

Tags: java, android, string, key

I have a String in my Android application (in Java) that is actually a key to encrypt and decrypt messages.

It's a simple String that I declare like this :

```
final static String myKey = "THEKEY";
```

The key never changes (and it will never be displayed in the app, nor sent through network or something else, it "stays" in the app).

Is there a way for people that have the APK to get the value of this string in my app?

If the answer is yes, what is the best way to be sure that the value of a String can stay secret?

Comment: use a third storage like a central management where the app communicates and retrieves the key value. Even a hex editor can display the string if someone searches

Comment: another way is to make the key an algorithm instead of static value, an algorithm if seen as encoded is also a "string" but not displayed as such in hex editors, plus an algorithm can dynamicaly generate a key from other settings values and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way for people that have the APK to get the value of this string in my app ?

Yes, via decompiling.

> what is the best way to be sure that the value of a String can stay secret ?

Remove it from the APK. Or, do not worry about it being discovered.

There are steps you can take to make it incrementally more difficult to retrieve the value, such as using [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard) to package your production app. However, this will not deter somebody who really wants the value.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that !